# Turn nested hash to two dimensional array in Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, algorithm, multidimensional-array, ruby-hash

I want to write a method that can receive a nested hash and return a nested array of two dimensional arrays.

```
hash_to_a({1=>2, 2=>3, {3=>4, 5=>6}=>7})  # [[1, 2], [2, 3], [[[3, 4], [5, 6]], 7]]
hash_to_a({{5=>{1=>3, 2=>4}}=>{7=>8}})    # [[[[5, [[1, 3], [2, 4]]]], [[7, 8]]]]
hash_to_a({5=>{1=>3, 2=>4}})              # [[5, [[1, 3], [2, 4]]]]
```

So far i've got this:

```
def hash_to_a(a_hash)
  result = []
  a_hash.each { |k, v|
    if k.is_a?(Hash) 
      result << k.to_a
    else
      result << k
    end
    if v.is_a?(Hash)
      result << v.to_a
    else
      result << v
    end
  }
  result
end
```

The results are of course not desirable

```
hash_to_a({1=>2, 2=>3, {3=>4, 5=>6}=>7})  # [1, 2, 2, 3, [[3, 4], [5, 6]], 7]
hash_to_a({{5=>{1=>3, 2=>4}}=>{7=>8}})    # [[[5, {1=>3, 2=>4}]], [[7, 8]]]
hash_to_a({5=>{1=>3, 2=>4}})              # [5, [[1, 3], [2, 4]]]
```

How can I accomplish the wanted results? I also tried recusion but just can't wrap my mind around this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start with your simplest case, with no nesting.

```
def hash_to_a(hash)  # { 3 => 4 }
  hash.map do |k, v| # 3, 4
    [k, v]           # [3, 4] 
  end
end
```

Now the problem is that for the more complicated cases we don't want to return the key or value if it's a hash, we want to convert it from a hash first.

```
def hash_to_a(hash)
  hash.map do |k, v|
    [hash_to_a(k), hash_to_a(v)]
  end
end
```

This will blow up with our simple case because 3 does not have a method `#map`. This is because we're not handling the base case yet. Just takes a line of code to keep from trying to map things that aren't hashes. We want it to behave just like our first try: do nothing but return the key or the value.

```
def hash_to_a(object)
  return object unless object.is_a? Hash
  object.map do |k, v|
    [hash_to_a(k), hash_to_a(v)]
  end
end
```

And we're done.

```
hash_to_a({1=>2, 2=>3, {3=>4, 5=>6}=>7})  # [[1, 2], [2, 3], [[[3, 4], [5, 6]], 7]]
hash_to_a({{5=>{1=>3, 2=>4}}=>{7=>8}})    # [[[[5, [[1, 3], [2, 4]]]], [[7, 8]]]]
hash_to_a({5=>{1=>3, 2=>4}})              # [[5, [[1, 3], [2, 4]]]]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use recursion

```
def h_to_a(h)
  h.map { |k,v| [k.is_a?(Hash) ? h_to_a(k) : k, v.is_a?(Hash) ? h_to_a(v) : v] }
end

h_to_a({ 1=>2, 2=>3, { 3=>4, 5=>6 }=>7 })
  #=> [[1, 2], [2, 3], [[[3, 4], [5, 6]], 7]]
h_to_a({ { 5=>{ 1=>3, 2=>4 } }=>{ 7=>8 } })
  #=> [[[[5, [[1, 3], [2, 4]]]], [[7, 8]]]]
h_to_a({ 5=>{ 1=>3, 2=>4 } })
  #=> [[5, [[1, 3], [2, 4]]]]
```

This obviously works with any level of nesting.

Answer (score 2):

What about this one:

```
def deep_to_array(hash)
  return hash unless hash.is_a?(Hash)
   array = hash.to_a
   array.each_with_index do |(k,v), index|
       array[index][0] = deep_to_array(k)
       array[index][1] = deep_to_array(v)
     end
  array
end
```

Or a concise one:

```
def deep_to_array2(hash)
  return hash unless hash.is_a?(Hash)
  hash.map do |k,v|
    [deep_to_array2(k), deep_to_array2(v)]
  end
end
```

Example:

```
deep_to_array(({1=>2, 2=>3, {3=>4, 5=>6}=>7}))
=> [[1, 2], [2, 3], [[[3, 4], [5, 6]], 7]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Yet another variation (using builtin `Hash#to_a`)

As class method:

```
class Hash
  def flatten_to_a
    to_a.map {|i| i.is_a?(Array) ? i.map {|i| i.is_a?(Hash) ? i.flatten_to_a : i} : i}
  end
end
```

As standalone method:

```
def f2a hash
  return hash unless Hash === hash
  hash.to_a.map {|i| i.is_a?(Array) ? i.map {|i| i.is_a?(Hash) ? i.flatten_to_a : i} : i}
end
```